# What am I missing in not having a gyroscope on my phone, when using Photosynth or other apps?

Tags: functionality

When I bought my Nokia Lumia 800, I was aware that it did not have a gyroscope or front-facing camera, but I didn't think they were that important to me.

Now that Skype is out I do miss the FFC, but I have never been bothered about the gyroscope until today, when I installed Photosynth.

When opening Photosynth I get a warning, saying that full functionality would not be available because of the lack of a gyroscope.  However, it does have a compass and accelerometer, and the app works as I would expect it to.

How differently would Photosynth work on a phone with a gyroscope, like the Lumia 900?

What else is the gyroscope useful for?  Just some games?

Comment: having a accelerometer would be enough however gyroscope is more accurate and hence it would make taking the pic much easier.

Comment: I added a link in my answer. Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gyroscope can improve the same data you already have. Some apps like compass apps would work better with this sensor.

I think gyroscope can precisely feel when you hang your phone with your arm straight and starts to turn yourself. I think compass fell when you turn only the phone in its own axis.

Edit:[Testing Photosynth with and without gyro](http://www.wpcentral.com/does-having-gyroscope-affect-photosynth).

Answer (score 2):

In theory using the gyroscope will be more accurate and wont lag/jump-around like using the compass+accelerometer found on the Lumia 800.

In [real-world usage](http://www.wpcentral.com/does-having-gyroscope-affect-photosynth) the gyroscope doesn't make a noticeable difference when compared to using the compass+accelerometer.

Comment: Also, I have had trouble making a complete spherical image on the Lumia 800. I am not sure if this is due to the lack of a gyroscope as http://www.mobiletechworld.com/2012/05/30/photosynth-for-windows-phone-finally-released/ seems to indicate.

Comment: More about Photosynth and gyro http://www.wpcentral.com/does-having-gyroscope-affect-photosynth

Comment: Great link, thanks. Have updated my answer.

Comment: Your link is only answer for taking a panorama. I wonder if it's really unnecessary?